# Nandikesvara Gayatri in Maha Narayana Upanisad

Tags: nandi, mahanarayana-upanishad, nandikeshvara, taittiriya-aranyaka

The Taittiriya Maha Narayana Upanisad is available in two forms (called by different names - long form, short form, Andra paatam etc). One of the versions / recensions contains Gayatri mantras for many deities including Sri Nandikeshvara.

The mantra is as follows -

> Om tatpurushAya vidmahE
>   chakratuNDAya DHeemaHI
>   tannO nandi prachOdayAt

My question is, does any one know the context / story / philosophical interpretation behind the expression `chakratuNDAya` ? Does it mean Nandikeshvara held the chakra tight / pressed (in HIS hands or mouth)? Which chakra / discus does the mantra refer to? What does it really mean, and what is the context? Any additional references in this regard would be helpful.

For additional reference & those interested - The Linga Purana gives a different gAyatri mantra as follows. But my question is about the mantra that appears in the Taittiriya MahA NArAyana Upanisad.

> OM harivaktrAya vidmahE
>   rudra vaktrAya DHeemaHI
>   tannO nandi prachOdayAt